# Prevent iMac from powering down TB3 port when it goes to sleep?

Tags: audio, imac, thunderbolt, power-management, firewire

I have a FW400 audio interface connected to my '17 iMac via some adapters and the TB3 port on the computer. When the iMac goes to sleep it's apparently powering down the TB3 port which in turn powers off my audio interface and then causes a very loud, potentially damaging, "thump" to occur through the attached monitors.

I've taken to powering down the monitors, but I'd like to not have to do this as it's inconvenient with my current setup.

Is there a way to keep the TB3 port powered during sleep? There are no apparent settings for this in the Energy Saver pane in System Preferences:

[image: Energy Saver pane in System Preferences]

Comment: you can prevent mac from sleeping altogether.  Use 3rd party apps to do so.

Comment: @jmh - Perhaps the OP needs the iMac to sleep at times and does not wish to keep it running 24/7. Ian C. - Although pricy, the [Elegato Thunderbolt 3 Dock](https://www.elgato.com/en/dock/thunderbolt-3) has an external power source. I was unable to find details on the Elegato website about whether the TB3 ports on the dock provide power when the computer is set to sleep. You can [send Elegato a form-based email](https://help.elgato.com/customer/portal/emails/new) and ask this question.

Comment: Just a suggestion if all else fails.

Comment: Yea, I'd like it to go to sleep, but not power down the TB3 port in the process.